# Tracing a curve along itself - can the result have holes?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, continuity, connectedness, curves

Let $\varphi:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$ be a continuous curve (not necessarily injective) with $\varphi(0)=(0,0)$. Let $f:[0,1]^2\to\Bbb R^2$ be defined as $f(s,t)=\varphi(s)-\varphi(t)$.

> **Question**: Is the image $f([0,1]^2)$ always *simply connected*?

The set $f([0,1]^2)$ can be thought of as the trace of the mirror curve $-\varphi$ when slided along $\varphi$. See the image below for an example.

$\qquad\quad$[image]

This problem came up to me in some non-trivial topological context but I consider it interesting in its own right. I am optimistic it can be proven with sufficiently advanced topological machinery, but might there be an elementary proof (as elementary as the term "simply connected")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There can be holes, even for very reasonable curves. For example, a $\varphi$
like

[image: a polygonal path with vertices (-1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 2), (-2, 2), (-2, 0), (2, 0), (2, -2), (0, -2), (0, -1), (1, -1)]

will produce $f([0,1]^2)$ like

[image: a blob with two holes]

which is clearly not simply connected.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for this counterexample.